# Dynamic to Static URL redirection in IIS

Tags: url, iis, web-config

I want to redirect the dynamic URLs to the static URLs via web.config. But right now I am not getting any redirections via the web.config file that I have uploaded. The dynamic URLs are as below:
 *- http://www.greatmathworksheets.com/?page=grade-worksheets-list&levelid=11*
and so on like levelid=12 
etc. And static URLs to be redirected are as below
 *- http://www.greatmathworksheets.com/grade-based-curriculums-11*
and so on like levelid=12

Please let me know what should I do so that the URLs get redirected. Please help me.

The web.config file is as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="Rule 1">
                <match url="(.*)" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.greatmathworksheets\.com$" negate="true" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.greatmathworksheets.com/{R:1}" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 2" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^index\.php$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.greatmathworksheets.com/" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 3" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^([a-z]+)$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?page={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 4" stopProcessing="true">
                <match url="^contact-us$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?page=contact-us" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule> 
    <rule name="Rule 7">
            <match url="^grade-based-curriculum$" ignoreCase="false" />
            <action type="Rewrite" url="?page=grade_level_curriculum" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 8">
                <match url="^activity-based-curriculum$" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?page=skill_level_curriculum" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>        
    <rule name="Rule 13">
                <match url="activity-based-curriculums-(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?page=worksheets-list&amp;levelid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>
            <rule name="Rule 14">
                <match url="grade-based-curriculums-(.*)" ignoreCase="false" />
                <action type="Rewrite" url="?page=grade-worksheets-list&amp;levelid={R:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
            </rule>

 <rule name="Rule 15" stopProcessing="true">
                  <match url="(.*)/$" ignoreCase="false" />
                 <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
  <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="page=inquiry" />
                       </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect"        url="http://www.greatmathworksheets.com/inquiry" redirectType="Permanent" />
            </rule> 
        </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Thank you,

Nitin

Comment: What doesn't work? Do you want a rewrite or redirect? You should give a clear name to your rules.